# Start Rails server automatically after boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scripting, ubuntu

I need to cd to a directory and run the 'rails server' command after bootup.
example

cd /home/bab/rails/app/

then when am in the app directory it runs the rails server command.

Can some1 help me with this...using ubuntu 9.10 and rails 3.0.0

Comment: Better then start rails server with `rails s` I suggest to use http server. Nginx or Apache. It is easy to config it for auto start or bootup.

Comment: and better to ask this kind of questions on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

try to add to `/etc/rc.local` this:

```
ruby /path/to/your/app/script/rails s -P /path/to/your/app/tmp/pids/server.pid -c /path/to/your/app/config.ru -d
```

But better to use `passenger gem` here with Nginx or Apache

http://modrails.com/

It is easy to setup and easy to use

Comment: Easier, as well as better in terms of security and performance. Here is a recent example of [how to setup passenger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932833/start-rails-server-automatically-after-reboot/23056985#23056985). Took me 30 minutes to setup.

Comment: Im facing the same problem. after add ur code into rc.local it still doesnt auto start. is the format problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I've was getting the same error with RVM, ruby, and rails. My directory is `/home/user/rails-project/`. Putting this in `.bashrc` allows me to use the "rvm" command:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

`server$:which rails`:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails
```

The above shows the current rails bin.

So, the final command in `rc.local` is:

```
su user-c  "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; cd /home/user/rails-project/ ; /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails s -d -e production"
```

You can use this code in `rc.local` to debug:

```
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log      # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution
```

Use `sudo service rc.local start` for testing without a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this in the following way:

create a script "rails.run" with the following line to start the ruby on rails with the desired user and parameters:

`sudo -H -u <username> bash -c '/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby bin/rails server --port=3000 --binding=ip_address -d'`

Then add the script in the rc.local file with a simple line such as:

**/home/username/rails.run**