# Start rails server with passenger, using commands in "rc.local"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, configuration, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

My system `etc/rc.local` file have following commands but passenger doesn't start on system boot.

```
!bin/sh -e


service jasperserver start
cd /home/username/myapp
passenger start --deamonize

exit 0
```

**jasperserver** works fine with this command but i don't know that **jasperserver** start automatically when i reboot or the above command start **jasperserver**. I need to know is there any other file that should need to be edit?? I search alot about it but didn't get any satisfied answer

Comment: [Another rc.local queistion with answer.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584759/start-rails-server-automatically-after-boot

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the link below. It has all information that you need.

[Starting StandAlone Passenger On Startup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/2W0Z-mRabq4)